"Your system has run out of application memory" on Apple Silicon M3 Max 36 GB Memory! Why?
I've been using Macs for 15 years, starting from a 2009 MacBook Pro with 4 GB of RAM, then upgrading to a 2016 MBP with 16 GB of RAM, and now, since last December (2023), upgraded to my first Apple Silicon Mac, an M3 Max 16" MBP.
For context, the first MBP has 320 GB of spinning storage, the second has 500 GB of SSD, and this one has a 2 TB SSD.
Never until yesterday I had received the message shown here:

"Your system has run out of application memory". I've been using the same kind of apps since 2009, and always had plenty of apps open at the same time, and I'm doing nothing really different now that I wasn't doing before. I regularly (at least once per week) restart or shut down the Mac.
This is from Activity Monitor just after the message came up:

I initially thought this was Acrobat since after quitting it (which was using about 3.5 GB of memory with no open document at all...) the situation stabilised for a while, then it happened again yesterday, and today when I opened Illustrator. Just launching the app caused this message to pop up.
I have read previous posts on this same issue but no one seemed to relate to Apple Silicon. Again, on Intel, I have never had this, and with much less memory than I do. Also, look at the graph, no swap used at all. Shouldn't Mac just use Swap if there is an issue instead of asking the user to force quit apps?
I honestly do not understand what is going on here. The SSD is about 80% free!
Finally, I have been doing the same things since getting this Mac, and it had never happened before. Even if I launched all apps together at the same time, this should just not happen, and the system should manage memory far better than this.
For the records, I am not noticing any slowdown in the way the Mac behaves, the CPU usage is not stressed at all.
What can / should I do?

Great details. If you restart the OS, get a second measurement (or take three measurements if you can start without any apps running - the third after you’ve started all the same apps). This likely is routing memory leaks and memory fragmentation, but some more data may be needed to diagnose this remotely. Weekly restarts were not enough for us running adobe heavy software and some ram hungry web sites and apps so we had production staff reboot daily since this would crop up after three days in some cases with software that is messy with RAM.

Also, start tracking which apps use energy - those that hit the CPU are likely the culprits, not the ones shown trying to make due with scraps the other programs left behind

There are quite a few questions about this situation, some of the answers might be helpful for further analysis: https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Your+system+has+run+out+of+application+memory

You can sort activity monitor by size - click on the column heading

@bmike : I have restarted and, for the first couple of hours, nothing has happened. I find it interesting that, even with very few apps running with not that many docs open I get a memory usage total of 28 GB! No swap, so far. Since the majority of those reports happened under Adobe software, I imagine something may be wrong there. Example: "Creative Cloud UI Helper (Renderer), what is that? 300 MB of memory! Then "Open and Save Panel Service (Sibelius)" with no Open/Save panel anywhere (160 MB!)?

Adobe Cloud is the problem, even if you try to uninstall it, it’s everywhere, running node and services and web servers and license check and surveillance and more. It used to be a very well designed set of programs. It’s worth eschewing now for someone wanting an uptime of months or more. Good luck @NotationMaster

I need to make some research on whether Affinity Publisher and Designer are able to completely take it over. I would still need some kind of access to fonts, though. I use quite a few of the Adobe ones.

Its a bit odd to me that no Swap is used - is that something expected? My (intel) MBP always uses some...

@X_841 : from what I understand of the Swap process, it is not allowed to use it for app memory rather for document memory. But I am not sure... the fact that there is no swap and that the Adobe apps suddenly requested so much memory to require a force quit (without any system slowdown) is a clear symptom that the apps themselves have issues in their code.

Next time look in the memory section of Activity Monitor (there's CPU, Memory, Energy, Disk, and Network). "Force Quit Applications" only shows apps, Activity Monitor shows all processes. And app memory does (kind of) use the swap file. It uses the space on your drive where the application is stored for swapping the app. Just doesn't count it as "swapping".
